# Como leer un rango en visual basic para excel y obtener los valores en las celdas de dicho rango

Tags: array, excel, vba

quisiera saber como leer un rango en una UDF de visual basic para excel, el objetivo es que el usuario ingrese unos cuantos rangos, la función mire que valores hay en dichos rangos, haga ciertas operaciones matematicas y al final de como resultado unos valores.

Como tengo pensada la función funcionaria de la siguiente manera.

```
Function Fun1(Rango As Range) As Double
Dim Fun As Double
Dim celda As Range
Dim cont As Integer
cont = 0

For Each celda In Rango.Cells
 Fun(cont) = celda.Value
 cont = cont + 1
Next celda

Fun1 = Fun(1)

End Function
```

Es maso menos eso lo que no se realizar, agradecería la ayuda, cualquier otra información que requiera adicionar me la hacen saber para colocarla.

Answer (score 2):

Gente luego de mucho intentarlo encontre la respueste a continuación anexo un código donde se solicita un rango y los valores de ese rango los devuelve en la celda donde se llame la función.

```
Function Ejemplo4(rango As Range) As Variant
Dim Fun() As Variant
ReDim Fun(rango.Count)
Dim celda As Range
Dim cont As Double

Fun = rango
Ejemplo4 = Fun

End Function
```